# Как исправить ошибку при компиляции?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct DBTable
{
string title, line;
int n;
};


void readTable();

void main()
{
    system("chcp 1251 > null");
    FILE *sf, *suf, *bf, *af, *mt;
    DBTable line;
    sf = fopen("Students.txt", "a+b");
    suf = fopen("Subjects.txt", "a+b"); 
    bf = fopen("Books.txt", "a+b");
    af = fopen("Abonements.txt", "a+b");

    readTable();
    system("pause");

}
void readTable()
{
    ifstream sf("Students");
    ifstream suf("Subjects.txt");
    ifstream bf("Books.txt");
    ifstream af("Abonements.txt");

    char buf[20], real[20];
    sf.getline(buf,20);
    char *leftS = strtok(buf, "|");
    cout << leftS;


    //printf("%s \n",real);

}
```

Сама ошибка:

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
>   _First was nullptr.
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

Comment: @ Похоже здесь неправильно указано имя файла ifstream sf("Students");, а потому файл не открыт, и данная команда sf.getline(buf,20); вызывает ошибку. Кроме того смысл вашего кода совершенно не понятен. Заем вы пытаетесь открыть одни и те же файлы двумя различными способами?

Comment: О какой "ошибке при компиляции" идет речь? Процитированное вами сообщение явно указывает на ошибку при *выполнении*.

Comment: Именно **при компиляции** у вас совсем другая ошибка - компилятору неизвестно, что такое `DBTable` :) Если эту строку выбросить - то см. комментарий  @VladfromMoscow...

Answer (score 0):

Я очень молодец. Файл то пустой, а я пытаюсь вывести ничего. Всем спасибо за ответы). Заполнил файл кракозябрами с разделителями и все заработало